# Cant access Hasura console in macbook m2

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, graphql, hasura, hasura-docker

I am trying to setup `hasura`/`graphql` API in `docker compose` environment and the server starts well.

However, when I try to access the console by running `hasura console` it returns an error.

The error is:

```
FATA[0000] making http request failed
Get "http://localhost:8080/v1/version": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

here is my config.yaml file

```
version: 3
endpoint: http://localhost:8080
admin_secret: <admin-secret>
metadata_directory: metadata
migration_directory: migrations
actions:
  kind: synchronous
  handler_webhook_baseurl: http://localhost:4000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  express:
    container_name: test_server
    network_mode: host
    build:
      dockerfile: express.dockerfile
      context: .
      # args:
      #   - PORT=${PORT}
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
  graph:
    container_name: graph_api
    network_mode: host
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.21.0
    depends_on:
      - express
    #environment:
    #  HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true"
    env_file:
      - .env
```

hasura cli version

```
INFO hasura cli  version=v2.23.0-beta.1
```

Comment: Can you please post complete details. Also for your reference can you please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for asking a question.